# Why if for all $N$, $span\{y_n\}_{n=1}^N=span\{x_n\}_{n=1}^N$ then $\overline{span\{y_n\}_{n=1}^\infty}=\overline{span\{x_n\}_{n=1}^\infty}$

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis, analysis

My lecturer stated the following as part of a proof using the Gram-Schmidt process:

If $\forall N\in \mathbb{N}$
$$\operatorname{span}\{y_m\}_{n=1}^N=\operatorname{span}\{x_n\}_{n=1}^N$$

then it immediately follows that:

$$\overline{\operatorname{span}\{y_n\}_{n=1}^\infty}=\overline{\operatorname{span}\{x_n\}_{n=1}^\infty}$$

He noted that it should not concern us that we have infinity in the bottom part since "we can stop after $N$ for all $N$".

What did he mean by that? As far as I know, we cannot use induction here to reach the infinite case. So what is the actual reason behind this claim?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The span of an infinite set is defined to be the set of **finite** linear combinations of that set. So, if $a \in \text{span}(y_n)_{n=1}^\infty$, then for some $N$, $$a \in \text{span}(y_n)_{n=1}^N \, = \,\text{span}(x_n)_{n=1}^N \, \leq \, \text{span}(x_n)_{n=1}^\infty.$$
The inequality goes in the other direction by the same argument, giving us $$ \text{span}(x_n)_{n=1}^\infty = \text{span}(y_n)_{n=1}^\infty,$$
after which we may take the closure of both sides.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Let $x\in \overline{\hbox{span}\{y_n\}_{n=1}^{\infty}}$, then $W \cap \hbox{span}\{y_n\}_{n=1}^{\infty} \neq \emptyset $ for all neighbourhood $W$ of $x$. Therefore, there exists $w \in W$ such that $w=\sum_{k=1}^{N}\alpha_k y_{n_k}$ with $n_1<n_2<\cdots<n_N$. Since $\hbox{span}\{y_n\}_{n=1}^{n_N}=\hbox{span}\{x_n\}_{n=1}^{n_N}$ we can write $w$ as a linear combination of $\{x_{1},\dots,x_{n_N}\}$. Therefore, $W \cap \hbox{span}\{x_n\}_{n=1}^{\infty} \neq \emptyset $.

Comment: What's $W$ here?

Comment: An arbitrary neighbourhood of $x$.